# manual object constructor call

Tags: c++, class, visual-c++, gcc, constructor

Can you please tell me if it is possible to **call object constructor manually**? I know it's wrong and I would never do something like that in my own code and I know I can fix this problem by creating and calling initialization function, however the problem is that I stumbled at a case where there are thousands of lines of code in object's and its parents' constructors...

```
class MyClass()
{
    MyClass() { }
    virtual ~MyClass();

    void reset()
    {
         this->~MyClass();
         this->MyClass::MyClass(); //error: Invalid use of MyClass
    }
};
```

Comment: If there are thousands of lines of code in ANY function, something is very wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can still move construction/destruction into separate functions and call those directly. i.e.

```
class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass() { construct(); }
    ~MyClass() { destruct(); }

    void reset() {
        destruct();
        construct();
    }

private:
    void construct() {
        // lots of code
    }

    void destruct() {
        // lots of code
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much, everybody! I can't believe I could have missed this solution...

Answer (score 3):

You could use placement new syntax:

```
this->~MyClass(); // destroy
new(this) CMyClass(); // construct at the same address
```

Answer (score 2):

A constructor is called using placement new

```
new (address) MyClass();
```

This constructs a MyClass in an empty space at address.

Would never do this **inside** the class though!

**Edit**
If you already have an object of the right type, and want to assign it default values, an alternative is

```
*this = MyClass();
```

which creates a new object with default values and assigns that value to your existing object.

Comment: The problem is that MyClass is always being created on stack

Comment: @Ryan: If you do it as @sharptooth shows, then it will be no memory leak, as you already have the memory.