# delete this and placement new of virtually derived class

Tags: c++, templates, virtual, placement-new

```
class base {
    int a;
protected:
    template<class T>
    class derived;
public:
    base() {}
    virtual ~base() {}
    virtual void func() {}
    static base* maker();
};

template <class T>    
class base::derived 
    : public base
{
public: 
    derived() {}
    virtual ~derived() {}
    virtual void func() {
        this->~derived(); //<--is this legal?
        new (this) derived<int>(); //<--is this legal?
    }
};

base* base::maker() {
    return new derived<double>();
}

int main() {
    base* p = base::maker(); //p is derivedA<double>
    p->func(); //p is now derivedA<int>
    delete p; //is the compiler allowed to call ~derived<double>()?
}
```

This is a Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example of my code (which is basically reinventing `any_iterator` for my own growth).

The question reduces down to: is it undefined behavior to destroy `this` and reconstruct `this` with a different type virtually derived from the same base, when neither has any additional members over the shared base?  Specifically, are compilers *allowed* to call keep track of the static type, or is that technically nonconforming?

[EDIT] Several people pointed out that compilers may call the incorrect destructor if `derivedA` is created on the stack.  (1) I can't find anything in the standard that allows compilers to do so. (2) That was aside from what I *intended* by my question, so I have changed the code to show that `derived` *cannot* be placed on the stack.  `base` can still be on the stack though.

Comment: Does not matter if it is correct or not. Nobody in their right mind would do that. Even if it does works it would be a maintenance nightmare, thus it will never happen in real code.

Comment: Off topic: Why the cast to the monstrous pointer? Placement-new wants a void pointer. Perhaps your case is a candidate for dynamic-cast-to-void! `void * p = dynamic_cast<void*>(this); new (p) T;`

Comment: I'm quite sure that this would break badly if used for variables declared on the stack.

Comment: @KerrekSB Do I sense that you're trying to have fun with what you learned from a question earlier this week? :)

Comment: @MatteoItalia: Nope, that's totally fine (see my answer). w00te: for a minute there I thought we might be onto something here, but now I'm convinced it Makes No Sense :-(

Comment: @Kerrek: actually in your answer you are supporting my idea (my concern was about the static type thing).

Comment: @MatteoItalia: Perhaps, but I was objecting to your "stack" argument. The storage class of an object has no role in this question.

Comment: @Kerrek: the stack thing was just the first example of a variable with a well defined static type that came to my mind...

Comment: Related: [Is it valid to directly call a (virtual) destructor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036086/is-it-valid-to-directly-call-a-virtual-destructor), [Is `new (this) MyClass();` undefined behaviour after directly calling the destructor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224121/is-new-this-myclass-undefined-behaviour-after-directly-calling-the-destru)

Comment: @Xeo: Those have good info.  Not _quite_ duplicates though. (else I'd have my answer!)

Comment: That's why I said "related". :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that's clearly not OK.

As a preface, and object's lifetime can indeed be ended by calling the destructor, but you're only allowed (and required) to construct a new object *of the same type* in its place:

```
{
  Foo x;
  x.~Foo();
  ::new (&x) Foo;
}  // x.~Foo() must be a valid call here!
```

Remember that at scope's end the destructor will be invoked!

But in your case you're constructing an *entirely different* object:

```
::new (&x) Bar;   // Bar = DerivedA<int>
```

Clearly if `sizeof(Bar)` exceeds `sizeof(Foo)` this cannot be OK.

(Perhaps if you can make additional guarantees on the object sizes, as well as on the alignment guarantees, we can think about this further.)

*Update:* Even if you're thinking, OK, so those types are derived from the same base, so invoking the destructor brings virtual happiness, I'm still pretty sure that that's a violation. In this static setting, the compiler may well resolve the virtual call statically, so you're breaking the compiler's assumptions if you change the dynamic type of the thing pointed to by `&x`.

*Update 2:* Another thought on the same matter: The *static type* of `*&x` is known, and I think you have to respect that. In other words, the compiler has no reason to factor in the possibility that the *static type* of a local variable changes.

Comment: In my OP is noted that they are guaranteed to be the same size.  On your updates: Is that allowed in a conforming compiler?  Am I violating specs or is the compiler? (Assuming it doesn't work. I haven't actually tested yet.)

Comment: @MooingDuck: If your example is **literal** to the letter, then you don't have need any virtual hierarchy nor any destructors, so you're probably fine. My answer targets a somewhat more general situation, I guess.

Comment: I reread Matteo Italia and realized that he was finding potential errors in my SSCCE that are _not_ in my real code, so I updated the question to clarify that `derived` cannot be created on the stack.  I don't think that affects your answer though.

Comment: In the real code, `base` contains a buffer that the `derived` is placement-new-ing `T`, into, and the virtual members act on that `T`.  The virtual hierarchy is needed.

Comment: @Mooing: If you have virtual functions anyway, why have a buffer in the base class instead of just having a value of the correct type in the derived class?

Comment: @Xeo: `base base::operator*=(const base& b);`  Also, I can make them on the stack.

Comment: @MooingDuck: after your edit, here's a possibly somewhat saner pattern you might consider: `void * addr = ::operator new(required_size); DerivedA<Foo>*p = ::new (addr) DerivedA<Foo>; p->~Derived<Foo>(); DerivedB<Foo>*q = ::new (addr) DerivedA<Bar>;`

Comment: @KerrekSB: Actually, I realized I'd rearranged my design so that the `base` is destroyed and recreated by the parent object, and simply forgot while coding the `base` object.  My code is actually much more sane than the question implies (now that I fixed it).  However, the question remains, is this UB?  Xeo's linked questions imply that it can _lead_ to UB if the destructor throws an exception.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that is not valid code for several reasons:

1. If the inserted type isn't the same size bad things will happen (I'm not quite sure but I think the standard doesn't make to much promises about the size of a type, so from the theoretical vantage point it might be hard to prove that they have the same size (through in praxis they most likely will))
2. if the type of the variable is statically known (probably due to it beeing constructed on the stack, but it in theory it could do the same thing if it can see the allocaiton and prove that the pointer couldn't have been modified) the compiler can feel free to statically reolve virtual method calls (e.g. a destructor) and use them which would obviously break the code
3. Even if the type of the variable is not statically known I'm quite sure the compiler can assume that it's type won't change during it's lifetime (The pointer can't change inside the function so it should be able to assume the pointed to type doesn't either). Therefore while it can't statically resolve methods it could possibly reuse the vmt pointer from previous invocations of virtual methods (e.g. the one changing the type)

Edit: now that I think about it doesn't this break strict aliasing rules, since after the placement new this points to a non compatible type? granted it isn't explicietly accessed in the function again, but I don't think it can be guranteed that there won't be accesses inserted by the compiler (highly unlikely though). Anyways this would mean that the compiler can assume that this kind of action won't happen.

**Edit:** When looking at the new C++ Standard I found that [basic.life] (§3.8.5) gives what is basically the same thing as an example of undefined behaviour (it doesn't actually destroy the object, but I don't see how that could make matters better):

```
#include<cstdlib>
structB{
    virtual void f();
    void mutate();
    virtual ~B();
};
struct D1:B { void f(); };
struct D2:B { void f(); };
void B::mutate(){
    new(this)D2; //reuses storage—ends the lifetime of *this
    f(); //undeﬁned behavior
    ...=this; //OK, this points to valid memory
}
void g(){
    void* p = std::malloc(sizeof(D1) + sizeof(D2));
    B* pb = new(p)D1;
    pb->mutate();
    &pb; //OK: pb points to valid memory
    void* q = pb; //OK: pb points to valid memory
    pb->f(); //undeﬁned behavior, lifetime of *pb hasended
}
```

This should prove that this is not allowed.

Comment: (1) The objects _are_ the same size for the purposes of the question.  (2/3) The core of the question is if a conforming compiler is allowed to do that.

Comment: @MooingDuck: The example extracted from the standard (draft) points in the direction that the compiler is allowed to do that.